# Aplication name

Tags: терминология

Возникли проблемы с расшифровкой аббревиатуры, буду очень рад и благодарен за помощь. Ещё бы хотелось знать где можно посмотреть через какие протоколы они работают. 
**SAP AMP,
SAP BSP,
SAP BWP,
SAP UPP,
SVFE**

Comment: какой аббревиатуры? у вас там несколько. SAP - это https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAP (System Analysis and Program) Системный анализ и разработка программ.[Wiki]
APP = **Application!** Приложение!